# How to split multi labelled dataset into many rows with each row having a single label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame which looks like this?

```
Feature      Class
text1        [label1, label2]
text2        [label2, label3]
```

What is the best way to do this?

```
Feature      Class
text1        label1
text1        label2
text2        label2
text2        label3
```

NOTE: In the initial table, class value is a Python list containing the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and flatten lists by [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Feature' : df['Feature'].values.repeat(df['Class'].str.len()),
    'Class' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['Class'].values.tolist()))
})
print (df)
  Feature   Class
0   text1  label1
1   text1  label2
2   text2  label2
3   text2  label3
```